# How to increase Screen Resolution of Kinect Color Image Frame?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to increase the screen resolution of Kinect ColorImageFrame. Right now its generating the ColorFrame in 640X480 and i want to increase it to 1280X720. But in Depth Image Frame properties the highest available resolution is `640x480Fps30`. Kindly tell me how to increase the resolution of ColorFrame.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are wanting to simple include the visual size, stick the output in a UI element of that size.  If you are actually wanting to get more pixels out of the hardware, you can't.

Comment: sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution1280x960Fps12)  is that all you are trying to do? The colorStream.Enable has a parameter for the image quality

Comment: in reality the old kinect effectivly has 640x480/8 true depth pixels its not detailed as advertised, most pixels are triangulated.